# Error getting ImageReader parsing DICOM image

Tags: java, dicom

I try to implement sample piece of code to get image from DicomObject:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import org.dcm4che2.data.DicomObject;
import org.dcm4che2.imageio.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReadParam;
import org.dcm4che2.io.DicomOutputStream;

....

public static BufferedImage getPixelDataAsBufferedImage(byte[] dicomData)
        throws IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(dicomData);
    BufferedImage buff = null;
    Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM");
    ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) iter.next();
    DicomImageReadParam param = (DicomImageReadParam) reader.getDefaultReadParam();
    ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(bais);
    reader.setInput(iis, false);
    buff = reader.read(0, param);
    iis.close();
    if (buff == null) {
        throw new IOException("Could not read Dicom file. Maybe pixel data is invalid.");
    }
    return buff;
}
```

When ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) iter.next(); I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/media/imageio/stream/StreamSegmentMapper
at org.dcm4che2.imageioimpl.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReaderSpi.createReaderInstance(DicomImageReaderSpi.java:146)
at javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi.createReaderInstance(ImageReaderSpi.java:320)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(ImageIO.java:529)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(ImageIO.java:513)
at dcm4.dcmTools.loadImage(dcmTools.java:61)
at dcm4.Dcm4.main(Dcm4.java:87)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.media.imageio.stream.StreamSegmentMapper
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 6 more
```

Does anyone knows What is wrong??? I use JDK7 64 on Windows7 64

Comment: Are you using Maven in your Java project?

Comment: I've creted JavaProject in NetBeans 7.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given exception indicates that you have a runtime dependency on Java Advanced Imaging (JAI).  You need additional JARs not provided with the standard JDK.

Here are the **JAI** and **JAI ImageIO Tools** installation instructions:

http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/INSTALL.html#Windows
http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/INSTALL-jai_imageio.html#Windows

You can download the installers here:

http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/
http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/

Once you install JAI, you will need to include the extracted JARs in your project classpath.

## Maven

If using Maven, JAI and JAI ImageIO Tools can be used for your project without installers:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai_imageio</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks - I've downloaded jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586-jdk but when I try to install it I've got error like "need jdk 1.3 or higher". What's wrong???

Comment: I've installed jai-1_1_3-lib-windows-i586 and add to my project libs 3 jars wich were installed jai: jai_codec, jai_core and mlibwrapper but it not solve my problem - I still got exception. Any idea...

Comment: Thanks for updating with the working solution.  I will add a link to the `jai_imageio.jar` download.