# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/media/imageio/stream/StreamSegmentMapper

Tags: java, swing, jogl, dcm4che

I am Working on Image 3D rendering using jogl.

I got the following error.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0-FPSAWTAnimator-Timer0" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/media/imageio/stream/StreamSegmentMapper
    at com.jogamp.common.util.awt.AWTEDTExecutor.invoke(AWTEDTExecutor.java:58)
    at jogamp.opengl.awt.AWTThreadingPlugin.invokeOnOpenGLThread(AWTThreadingPlugin.java:103)
    at jogamp.opengl.ThreadingImpl.invokeOnOpenGLThread(ThreadingImpl.java:206)
    at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invokeOnOpenGLThread(Threading.java:172)
    at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:191)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:528)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AWTAnimatorImpl.display(AWTAnimatorImpl.java:75)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.display(AnimatorBase.java:443)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator$MainTask.run(FPSAnimator.java:170)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/media/imageio/stream/StreamSegmentMapper
    at org.dcm4che2.imageioimpl.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReaderSpi.createReaderInstance(DicomImageReaderSpi.java:146)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi.createReaderInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at TutorialPoint.Trial3DTexture.init(Trial3DTexture.java:191)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.init(GLDrawableHelper.java:601)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.init(GLDrawableHelper.java:623)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$8.run(GLCanvas.java:1254)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1101)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:978)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1282)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.media.imageio.stream.StreamSegmentMapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 27 more
finishLifecycleAction(com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator$3): ++++++ timeout reached ++++++ Thread-5
finishLifecycleAction(com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator$3): OK false- pollPeriod 17, blocking true, waited 1014/1000 - Thread-5
 - com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator[started true, animating true, paused false, drawable 1, totals[dt 0, frames 0, fps 0.0], modeBits 1, init'ed true, animThread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0-FPSAWTAnimator-Timer0,6,], exclCtxThread false(null)]
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Unknown Source)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.finishLifecycleAction(AnimatorBase.java:562)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator.stop(FPSAnimator.java:291)
    at TutorialPoint.Trial3DTexture$1$1$1.run(Trial3DTexture.java:82)
```

Please help me to fix the issue.

Thanks

Comment: it would be good if you will provide the code.

Comment: @khAn :In Trial3DTexture class, error line 191 is:image[i] = ImageIO.read(fileList[i]); // loading DICOM images.

Comment: @Deepti have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119680/error-getting-imagereader-parsing-dicom-image

Comment: Looks like the same error as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119680/error-getting-imagereader-parsing-dicom-image)

Comment: @SubOptimal : Thanks. Error solved by adding jai-imageio.jar in classpath, but got fatal error: "A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x5ef6de10, pid=2868, tid=3624." Searching to resolve this.

Comment: @Deepti Maybe for this one you should first investigate in the internet and if you cannot find a solution for your problem, rais a new question. But you would need to include more information about: the code you try to run, the JDK / operating system you are using. Only with a small piece (part of the error message) anyone would need to guess. People answering here do it in their spare time, for free and they (most probably) don't want to do all investigation for you.

Comment: Check that you use the same version of JOGL than the one used to compile the third party libraries that rely on it. It looks like a bug in one of them, it probably badly handles the position in a direct NIO buffer.

Comment: @SubOptimal : Yes, sure I will keep these things in mind. Thanks for guidance. :)